# Как определить в какой строке ListView нажата кнопка в приложении UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Вроде бы тривиальная задача, но что-то не выходит. Причем делал подобное в приложении Xamarin.Forms.
В общем есть ListView, привязка данных к коллекции. В ListView в каждой строке отображается кнопка. Необходимо при нажатии на эту кнопку определить к какому элементу коллекции привязана кнопка. Часть кода написал, а вот дальше не могу понять что делать. Пошу подсказать.
XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvShippings" IsItemClickEnabled="True" BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue" BorderThickness="2" Height="150">
                                        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Width="12"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Фабрика"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="140" Text="Ткань" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="42" Text="Заказ ткани" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="80" Text="Стоимость ткани, руб" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="60" Text="Кол-во, метров" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="80" Text="Доставка, руб" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Shipping">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{x:Bind Name_Factory}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="140" Text="{x:Bind Name_Fabric}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                                    <Button Width="32" Content="+" Click="ButtonFabricOrder_Click"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="10"/>
                                                    <TextBlock HorizontalTextAlignment="Right" Width="80" Text="{x:Bind FabricCost}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock HorizontalTextAlignment="Right" Width="60" Text="{x:Bind FabricQuantity}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock HorizontalTextAlignment="Right" Width="80" Text="{x:Bind ShippingCost}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <ListView.FooterTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Order">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Width="12"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="380" Text="Итого стоимость доставки ткани"/>
                                                    <TextBlock HorizontalTextAlignment="Right" Width="80" Text="{x:Bind ShippingFabricCost, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.FooterTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
```

C#:

```
private void ButtonFabricOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    StackPanel stackPanel = button.Parent as StackPanel;
    DataTemplate dataTemplate = stackPanel.Parent as DataTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Загляните в DataContext кнопки

Comment: @Андрей NOP Спасибо. Действительно все было очень просто.